# how to find conflicts in fstab file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl, fstab

some times we noticed about conflicts in /etc/fstab file
as the following example

**/dev/sdg appears twice  !**

**/data/sdb appears twice !**

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Wed Nov  9 13:26:03 2016
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg00-OS-linux_root /                       xfs     defaults        
0 0
UUID=cc749f07-ad72-49e8-ab19-ec6532f5e9 /boot                   xfs     
defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-OS-linux_var /var                    xfs     defaults        
0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-OS-linux_swap swap                    swap    defaults        
0 0


/dev/sdc /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdb /data/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sde /data/sde ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdf /data/sdf ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdd /data/sdd ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdg /data/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdg /data/sdg ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdh /data/sdh ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdi /data/sdi ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdj /data/sdj ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdk /data/sdk ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdl /data/sdl ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

we want to create simple verification to find conflicts on the first field or the second field in fstab file

what is the best syntax for this purpose ?

verification should find duplicate words in the first field or in the second field , ( **syntax line** should be short as possible )

expected output - **fail / ok**

&  ( should print all duplicated word from the first field / second field in case of fail )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk ' !/^#/ { if (seendev[$1]++) { print; ++rc; } if (seenmnt[$2]++) { print; ++rc; } } 
     END { exit rc }' < /etc/fstab
```

The above awk one-liner will print any lines that duplicated column 1 (device) or column 2 (mount-point), and will also exit with a non-zero return code if the above occurs.

Comment: +1. this would be more useful if it also printed the line number of duplicates.   e.g. `awk ' !/^#|^[[:space:]]*$/ { if (seendev[$1]++) { print NR ":\t" $0; ++rc; } if (seenmnt[$2]++) { print NR ":\t" $0; ++rc; } } 
     END { exit rc }' /etc/fstab`  (this version also avoids printing duplicate blank lines.  actually, it avoids the false-positive of detecting blank lines as duplicates of themselves)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Filter out comments and blank lines from /etc/fstab, pick 1st/2nd field,
# then sort and find duplicates.
DUP_DEVS="$(grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' /etc/fstab | awk '{ print $1;}' | sort | uniq -d)"
DUP_MOUNTS="$(grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' /etc/fstab | awk '{ print $2;}' | sort | uniq -d)"

if [ -z "$DUP_DEVS" ] && [ -z "$DUP_MOUNTS" ]; then
    echo "ok"
    exit 0
else
    echo "fail"
    if [ ! -z "$DUP_DEVS" ]; then
        echo "Duplicate devices:"
        echo "$DUP_DEVS"
    else
        echo "Duplicate mount points:"
        echo "$DUP_MOUNTS"
    fi
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution with **`awk`**:

```
awk '/^\/dev\//{ 
         if (devs[$1]++) dups[$1];
         if (data[$2]++) dups[$2] 
     }
     END{ 
         res="Ok"; 
         for (d in dups) { res="Fail\nDuplicates: "; break } 
         print "Result: "res; 
         for (d in dups) print d 
     }' /etc/fstab
```

The output:

```
Result: Fail
Duplicates: 
/dev/sdg
/data/sdb
```